# new placement в тот же указатель

Tags: c++

Читаю про new placement и попался такой пример:

```
int main(){
    int a = 234;
    int* p = new (p) int(a);   
    (*p)++;                       
 
    cout << *p << '\n';         //235
    cout << a << '\n';          //234
}
```

В комментариях к нему пишут, что :" данном случае p сырой указатель. Непосредственно ему память мы не выделяем. Но мы выделяем память переменной a".Не могу понять,placemen new же делается в уже готовый участок памяти, но в какой момент она(участок памяти) тогда создается в данном примере, если мы заранее не выделили ничего?

Comment: Этот пример безграмотный и не работает.

Comment: Интересно узнать, где же вы читаете, что такие примеры там приводят. Если что - здесь за ссылки на сторонние ресурсы не банят, можете публиковать смело.

Answer (score 0):

VC++ сразу заметил - использование неинициализированной переменной `p`. **Куда**, по какому адресу при этом будет выполняться запись?

Если мы напишем так - разница вроде как небольшая, нет?

```
int* p = 0;
p = new (p) int(a);
```

А попробуйте теперь [запустить на выполнение](https://ideone.com/bL4O3P)...

Первоначальный код - одно большое UB - запись в память по какому-то неопределенному адресу...

Comment: И как  размещать объект  по нулевому адресу?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Не понял? Именно это я и показал - что приведенный код не работает. Ведь с тем же успехом, что какой-то мусор, в `p` может быть нулевой адрес, и тогда слет по сути неминуем.